# Подключение stm32 к RPi через SPI

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, stm32, spi

Делаю адаптер SPI-CAN на основе stm32f103c8t6 для RPi 3 и столкнулся с рядом проблем и вопросов.

1) Программа на RPi. Для работы с SPI использую библиотеку bcm2835-spi. Вся программа зависает при попытке отправки сообщения:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include </home/pi/CAN_Process/src/bcm2835.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //SPI INIT
    if (!bcm2835_init())
    {
        printf("bcm2835_init failed. Are you running as root??\n");
        return 1;
    }
    bcm2835_spi_begin();
    bcm2835_spi_setBitOrder(BCM2835_SPI_BIT_ORDER_MSBFIRST);      // The default
    bcm2835_spi_setDataMode(BCM2835_SPI_MODE0);                   // The default
    bcm2835_spi_setClockDivider(BCM2835_SPI_CLOCK_DIVIDER_64); // 64 прескаллер
    bcm2835_spi_chipSelect(BCM2835_SPI_CS0);                      // The default
    bcm2835_spi_setChipSelectPolarity(BCM2835_SPI_CS0, LOW);      // the default

    uint8_t spi_write[11];
    uint8_t spi_read[11];

    //infinite
    while(1){
        for(uint8_t i=0;i<11;i++)spi_write=i;//Просто заполнение массива    
        bcm2835-spi-transfern(spi_write,11);//Строчка на которой всё зависает
    }
    bcm2835_spi_end();
    bcm2835_close();
    return 1;
}
```

Если у кого то есть готовый рецепт SPI для библиотеки WiringPI, то готов с радостью на неё перейти.

2) Настройка SPI. Так как частота процессора RPi 3 400 МГц и для тактирования SPI можно выбрать прескаллеры только кратные двум, а частота кварца Stm32 8 МГц и частоту SPI тоже нельзя выбрать любую, то нельзя выбрать одинаковые частоты. Я выбрал частоту SPI на RPi 6.250MHz. А на stm32 максимальную (18 Мбит/с), понадеявшись, что он всё равно будет синхронизироваться по шине CLK. Правильно это или нет?

3) Программа на stm32. Работаю через CubeMX и библиотеку HAL. При инициализации SPI, не инициализируется ножка для выбора Slave. Я понимаю, что у нас stm32 работает в качестве ведомого, но как тогда правильно реализовать работу шины CE со стороны stm32? У меня на эту шину SPI всего один ведомый, значит ли это, что выбор slave со стороны stm32 можно никак не обрабатывать? Большущее спасибо.

Comment: Третий вопрос снимается. Оказывается в настройках куба NSS ножку можно выставить

Comment: 2) SPI slave всегда *ведомый*, главное, чтобы успевал ваши данные из встроенного буфера вычитывать. То есть процессором в 8 МГц тактовой теоретически можно успевать обрабатывать поток с шины в 50 МГц (при наличии нескольких 4-8 или более байт буфера очереди). /CS в таком случае обычно садится прямо на контроллер аппаратных прерываний.

Comment: spi_write=i ??? Как это понимать?

Answer (score 0):

- Думаю зависание может происходить из-за того что функция вызывается очень быстро и без конца, забивая очередь. Попробуйте сделать вызов по нажатию кнопки, или вызов каждую секунду один раз.
- Правильно, можно и не максимальную.

Answer (score 0):

1. Есть опыт работы с SPI на RaspberryPi. Управлял экраном от Riverdi. Реализацию платформы можно посмотреть здесь [platform.h](https://github.com/OzhegovRoman/ControlUnit4_Software/blob/master/Libs/RiverdiEve/host_layer/platform.h), [platform.cpp](https://github.com/OzhegovRoman/ControlUnit4_Software/blob/master/Libs/RiverdiEve/host_layer/platform.cpp)

Если кратко, то инициализация SPI выполняется последовательными командами:

```
int wiringPiSetup();
int wiringPiSPISetup(int channel, int speed);
```

А запись и чтение командой `int wiringPiSPIDataRW (int channel, unsigned char *data, int len)`

Полное описание библиотеки в части SPI доступно тут: [wiringPiSPI](http://wiringpi.com/reference/spi-library/)

Кстати, обнаружил, что в моем коде я использую вместо `wiringPiSPISetup` команду `wiringPiSPISetupMode`, описание которой сейчас найти не могу.

2. Захват данных происходит при изменении уровня CLK (в соответствии с режимом SPI) поэтому общая тактовая частота для Master и Slave необязательна. Важно только чтобы все успевали работать на той частоте, которую Вы выставите.

Comment: _все успевали работать на той частоте, которую Вы выставите_ - как я понимаю, чтобы STM успеть обработать, то по хорошему, частота на RPI должна быть равна или не больше частоты на STM?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov. Я не очень понял Ваш вопрос. Поскольку STM работает в slave mode, то частота SPI устанавливается со стороны RPI. Частота SPI должна быть ниже, чем тактовая частота STM/N (где N~2-2.5) Т.е. при тактовой частоте  STM 32MHz (что для F103 норм), нормальная частота для SPI - 12MHz, выше не стоит поднимать частоту. Но вопрос требует более детального изучения. Для меня 12 MHz - это достаточно высокая частота, на которой появятся потери и искажения, и стоит ли вообще такую частоту использовать и как ее правильно использовать - большой вопрос.

Comment: Именно это и хотел услышать. Спасибо